# Ignore Until "Spacebar+I or V or X" - Regex Expression

Tags: regex, regex-group

So... I had a regex which worked just fine (wasn't pretty but worked), until the Roman Numerals reached more than X.
Currently my Regex looks like this:

```
(.*?)(^(X{1,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})$|^(I[XV]|V?I{1,3})$|^V$)*(.)( EP\. )(\d*)(.*)
```

The problem I have right now is that if roman numeral has value 10 or more it's is in 1st group which drives me nuts.
I need it to work in a way that all before roman numerals is ignored.

```
Test Text:
PEPA THE PIG XVI EP. 169 - BAD ENDING
```

Could you please help me fix the regex so it would actually do what it suppose to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should re-consider using anchors in the middle of a regex: `^` requires start of string and `$` requires the end of string.

Besides, `(.)` before `( Ep\. )` consume the space, and the `Ep` pattern cannot match it.

Consider using

```php
^(.*?)\b(X{1,3}(?:I[XV]|V?I{0,3})|I[XV]|V?I{1,3}|V)\b(.)\b(EP\.)\s*(\d+)(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S3SJ2L/2). You might still need to check what exactly you want to match with `(.)`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(X{1,3}(?:I[XV]|V?I{0,3})|I[XV]|V?I{1,3}|V)` - Group 2: one to three `X`s followed with `IX` or `IV`, or with an optional `V` and then zero to three `I`s, or `IX`, `IV`, or an optional `V` followed with one to three `I`s or `V`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(.)` - Group 3: any one char (other than a newline)
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(EP\.)` - Group 4: `EP.`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 5: one or more digits
- `(.*)` - Group 6:  any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible